# lag on a lag, PostgreSQL (obtaining the value 2 months before current month)

Tags: sql, postgresql

table_1

```
customer_id         month          subscription_price
1               April 2020         49.0
2               February 2020      19.0
3               August 2019        20.0
4               February 2021      39.0
5               April 2020         19.0
6               June 2018          59.0
7               January 2020       15.0
```

The table above contains the subscriptions of each customer id, by month, where 1 customer will have 12 rows if he subscribes for a year.

The query below

```
    SELECT customer_id as c_id,month
         ,lag(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as before
         ,subscription_price as current
         ,lead(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as after
    FROM schema.table st
```

returns table_2

```
     c_id     month          before  current after
0       1   April    2020   NaN     28.0    28.0
1       1   August   2020   28.0    28.0    28.0
2       1   December 2020   28.0    28.0    28.0
3       1   February 2020   28.0    28.0    28.0
4       1   February 2021   28.0    28.0    28.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
1000    50  June     2020   71.2    32.0    71.2
1001    50  March    2020   32.0    71.2    32.0
```

Based on table_2, I would like to make a new column that specifies:

```
case when before is null 
and before_2 is not null 
and current is not null 
then 'reactivation'
end as status
```

My question is:
How can I come up with the subscription_price two months before current month? (the column called before_2)

```
lag(lag(subscription_price) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc)) as before_2
```

returns `Programming Error`.

Comment: It would help if you showed example *results* that had reactivations.  I'm not sure your logic is as simple as you describe.  What does a customer look like when the customer does not subscribe?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for pointing that out. Indeed, the logic does not stop there. I include the conditional part just to show why I want to do the second lag.  Showing the other conditional statements are not very relevant to the specific problem asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LAG` and `LEAD` both take additional arguments - the one you care about is the second arg, `offset`:

```
SELECT customer_id as c_id,month
     ,lag(subscription_price, 2) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as before
     ,subscription_price as current
     ,lead(subscription_price, 2) over (partition by customer_id order by month asc) as after
FROM schema.table st
```

Just add an offset of 2, as shown above, and you should be good.